# Class not remaining on anchor when clicked on dynamic page

Tags: jquery, class, dynamic, anchor

I have a dynamic page here http://www.intelligen.info/index.html that replaces content when an anchor is selected from the nav on the left. The class 'current' should be added to and stay on the selected anchor, however it is not working. The selected anchor should have a line through it when selected. How can I  make this work?

here is the code:

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value for an attribute selector should be quoted, so change it to this:

```
$("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
```

It should work after that. You could achieve the same visual effect with the [`:target` pseudo selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#target-pseudo), which might be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `newHash` contains a `.` because it's `page.html`. The `.` is a special character in a jQuery selector, so you have two options. Escape it or wrap the value for your attribute equals selector in quotes. The latter is the easier of the two. Change this line:

```
$("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
```

to:

```
$('nav a[href="'+newHash+'"]').addClass("current");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the href or add a class to the "selected" (I guess clicked) element?

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
  $('nav a').removeClass('current');
  $(this).addClass('current');
}
```

This has to be outside of your `hashchange` or you trigger `hashchange` on click.